# How do I stop my own highlighting while inside another highlighting group?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have [a brace coloring plugin](https://github.com/oblitum/rainbow/blob/master/plugin/rainbow.vim) that highlights code like this:

[image]

but I want it to stop highlighting inside macros. What I tried so far was adding my highlighting groups to the `cPreProcGroup` syntax cluster which is used for exclusion in the definition of the `cDefine` group in `c.vim`:

```
syn region cDefine start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(define\|undef\)\>" skip="\\$" end="$" keepend contains=ALLBUT,@cPreProcGroup,@Spell
```

Appeding my groups to `cPreProcGroup` didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you open an issue in the plugin's issue tracker? Seems that at least that part of documentation is missing.

Comment: @IngoKarkat the plugin is a fork of mine, and there's already an issue for this, I'm trying fixes now, hence the question.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear from the question. Also, please show the definition of "my groups", especially their containment relationships. In general, your approach of adding to the `cPreProcGroup` exclusion cluster looks good.

Comment: @IngoKarkat in truth I think my approach is failed because that `ALLBUT` clause means, "this is the cDefine region, except this ones listed", but I want the contrary, I want my groups to be ignored, and everything be the cDefine region as aways, and not excluding them from such region.